# Оттягивание UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Возможно ли отключить оттягивание `UIScrollView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы анимация не происходила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Interface Builder или коде смените свойство bounces у UIScrollView на NO.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В коде

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

В IB

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]